# Finding square roots of complex number $u$

Tags: complex-numbers

A complex number $u$ is given by $u = -1+(4\sqrt{3})i$. Find the two square roots of $u$.

Now, I know we have to compare the equation with $a+bi$ but my text book doesn't square both sides in the equation $-1+(4\sqrt{3})i = a+bi$. Only the latter is squared.

Can you explain why?

Comment: Does your book say $$-1+(4\sqrt3)i=(a+bi)^2?$$ That seems like a good place to start.

Comment: If you're looking for the square root $r$ of any $u$, the equation to set up is $r^2 = u$, right?  For instance, if $u$ is just $9$, then we set up $r^2 = 9$, and then $r = \pm 3$.  We don't, for instance, set $r^2 = u^2$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I'm sorry but it does not say that.

Comment: @BrianTung Thank you very much. Your explanation has clarified my problem to some extent. 
One quick question, had it been whole square root of $u$, would we square both sides to find the roots then?

Comment: I don't know what is meant by "whole square root."

Comment: @BrianTung I meant $\sqrt{-1+(4\sqrt{3})i} = a+bi$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fast way uses the remark that, if $z=a+ib$, then $|z|=\sqrt{|u|}$, or $|z|^2=|u|$. So you have the equations
\begin{align}
&a^2-b^2=-1 \tag{1}\\
&2ab =4\sqrt 3 \tag{2}\\
&a^2+b^2=\sqrt{(-1)^2+16\cdot 3}=7\tag{3}
\end{align}
Equations $(1)$ and $(3)$ yield instantly
$$\begin{cases}
2a^2=6\\
2b^2=8
\end{cases}\iff a=\pm\sqrt {3},\quad b=\pm2.$$
Using eq. $(2)$, you know $a$ and $b$ have the same sign. Hence
$$z=\pm(\sqrt {3}+2i).$$

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps a lot. Also, I think you meant $a = \pm \sqrt{3}$?

Comment: Oh! yes. Sorry for the typo. And thanks for editing the answer!

Answer (score 0):

To solve $(a+bi)^2=c+di$ use $a^2-b^2=c,\,2ab=d$ to deduce $a^2+b^2=\sqrt{c^2+d^2}$ so $a^2=\frac{\sqrt{c^2+d^2}+c}{2},\,b^2=\frac{\sqrt{c^2+d^2}-c}{2}$. Of the four choices of $a,\,b$ satisfying these expressions for $a^2,\,b^2$, only two are consistent with $ab=\frac{d}{2}$. In this case $c=-1,\,d=4\sqrt{3}$ so $\sqrt{c^2+d^2}=7$ and $a^2=3,\,b^2=4$, and since $ab=2\sqrt{3}$ one square root is $\sqrt{3}+2i$.

Comment: Thank you very much but my question is why don't we square both sides of the equation?

Comment: @childsh I can't speak for your textbook. Maybe it has a typo. Or maybe it goes on to consider $(x+yi)^2=a+bi$, in a difference from my notation but not my method.

Comment: Your method is absolutely correct and yes, it does go on to consider the notation you mentioned. However, it was unclear to me as to why both sides aren't squared but that query has been resolved. Thank you so much for your time. I highly appreciate it.